# 2019 Moderator Election - We need more candidates!

Tags: discussion, election

The [nomination period for the 2019 election](https://tor.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) was scheduled to end in 30 minutes. However, in order for the election to proceed, we need to have *at least* as many candidates as there are slots (so, 2) — that way, as mentioned in the original announcement, we can have a non-competitive election. We have extended the deadline for nominations for an additional seven days.

We need leadership to come from within this community, the election can't move forward unless someone wants to take on the responsibility. Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? Now would be a great time to reconsider!

Comment: I have cancelled the election as the extra week didn't bring in another candidate. We'll need to decide on the next step.

Comment: I've finally regained my access! The password reset flat-out wouldn't work for me, so I had to go digging through a password manager on an old laptop to find it. Hopefully I can keep a better eye on things now.

Comment: Sent you an email, @AndrewLott: please try to get back to me there ASAP :)

Comment: Looks like something is going a bit wonky still as I can't seem to access much of anything again. Not sure what I need to do to fix that...

Comment: I sent you _another_ email about this, earlier today, @AndrewLott.