# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Tor's [first moderator election](https://tor.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close and the new moderator is:

[image: Alexey Vesnin]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Stig Atle Steffensen and Andrew Lott who will be stepping down as moderator.

This was a rather unusual election as [we had just one candidate for two positions](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355/2019-moderator-election-we-need-more-candidates). We've decided to go ahead and appoint Alexey so that this site has two moderators. But it's a precarious position for a site to be in. We usually prefer three active moderators. We're still kicking the tires on our [provisional election process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332180/results-of-pro-tempore-elections-experiment) and it seems we still might need to make some adjustments to it. Thank you for your patience on the results of this election.

Comment: 30 minutes later, the user has not been granted moderator privileges. Oversight?

Comment: @gparyani: No. It's a little odd timing since we normally do these on a Tuesday. Expect the new diamond in an hour or two.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder now, what's the plan for the other moderator position? It's not really standard to only have two mods and I'm sure the community could benefit with a third.

Comment: This would probably be better posted as a new question.

Comment: But bear in mind there are several other SE communities with only two moderators. - https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators